# Requirements Sign-Off

Tags: ms-solution-framework

Where do you sign-off requirements in MSF? Do you finish writing the functional specs in the planning phase and then you sign off with the client right before starting development.

NOTE: I'm working on a fixed scope fixed price contract so agile model will not work. Does that mean Iterative and Incremental approach will not work as well. In such scenario, cant i kick off development before finishing the planning phase.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a progrmaming question.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a fixed scope, fixed price contract, then surely you want agreement on a finished functional specification so that everyone is happy with what the end outcome will be.

The last thing you would want to do is start developing functionality that is neither agreed upon nor necessary as part of the fixed price and scope, as that will simply be an inefficient use of time.

By the Way, what is MSF- [Microsoft Solutions Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Solutions_Framework)?

Answer (score 0):

As you refer to Functional Specs, plural, you could always look to sign some of them off so development on those areas of functionality can begin and then work to finish the others. This avoids potential work on areas that will not be part of final delivery while allowing work to commence.

One of the Foundation Principles of [MSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Solutions_Framework) is

```
    Stay agile, expect change
```

Comment: Not sure how agile work in my case as detailed requirements (Functional Specs) for the whole project needs to be signed off for me to move forward to development or i can choose to sign off piece by piece althouh not sure if this is practical

Answer (score 0):

I certainly wouldn't start developing before the customer signs the contract.  And I can't imagine how they could do that until you give them a price.  And price is dependent on time.  And time is dependent on the features that the customer wants to pay for (you estimate the work).  So, that leads me to conclude that you would have to have the specs done before doing any work at all.

Which is of course why the concept of fixed price and scope has been proven time and time again to be inefficient.

Comment: This is mandatory when you work with clients such as public sector for example, in such cases you have to estimate based on scope given in RFP. Detailed requirements come later in the gathering phase.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you certainly want to get sign-off (or *project engagement*) prior to starting the project in earnest (even before taking a deposit)

nearly all the projects i do are fixed-price

on my proposal (which is a high-level listing of deliverables), i have this:

[image]

you can get more info about sign-off/project engagement from this article: [Writing Short, Easy to Read Fee Proposals (Part 2)](http://pm4web.blogspot.com/2010/04/writing-short-easy-to-read-fee_04.html)

--LM